# How to change 'react-ionicons' color on hover effect with React

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-typescript, ionicons

I have a component with a list of icons using react-ionicons like so:

```
export default function SocialIconsViewer() {

    return ( 
        <ul className="socials">
            <li><a href="www.twitter.com"><LogoTwitter/></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="www.twitter.com"><LogoFacebook
                    title={'Facebook'}
                    /></a>
            </li><li><a href="www.twitter.com"><LogoInstagram 
                    title={'Instagram'}
                    /></a>
            </li><li><a href="www.twitter.com"><LogoYoutube 
                    title={'Youtube'}
                    /></a>
            </li><li><a href="www.twitter.com"><Mail 
                    title={'E-mail'}
                    /></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    );
}
```

I am trying to create a hover effect over these icons in the css file that imported here:

```
.socials {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.socials li {
  list-style: none;
}
.socials li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--black);
  font-size: 1.75em;
  transition: 300ms;
}
.socials li a:hover {
  color: crimson;
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work and I am having a hard time finding information to work with react-ionicons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no imports in your component code.

```
import {
  LogoTwitter,
  LogoFacebook,
  LogoInstagram,
  LogoYoutube,
  Mail,
} from "react-ionicons";
```

This is a very strange situation, because `hover` with `background-color` works fine with your Code but `color` `hover` doesn't! ??
Maybe it's the package's fault, I don't know for sure.

I spent a lot of time on it.... and found an alternative approach. I hope you will like it.

---

You could use  [react-icons](https://react-icons.github.io/react-icons) you need to properly **install** them and **import** them.

```
npm install react-icons --save
```

---

Example

```
import { FaBeer } from 'react-icons/fa';

export default function Question() {
    render() {
        return <h3> Lets go for a <FaBeer />? </h3>
    }
}
```

---

Your component after the changes

```
import { FaFacebook, FaTwitter, FaYoutube, FaInstagram } from "react-icons/fa";

export default function SocialIconsViewer() {
  return (
    <ul className="socials">
      <li>
        <a href="https:://facebook.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <FaFacebook />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://instagram.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <FaInstagram />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://twitter.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <FaTwitter />
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="https://youtube.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer">
          <FaYoutube />
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}
```

---

Your `Css` styles works properly (hover effect) if we use `global.css` file.

```
.socials {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 30px;
  z-index: 4;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.socials li {
  list-style: none;
}
.socials li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--black);
  font-size: 1.75em;
  transition: 300ms;
}
.socials li a:hover {
  color: crimson;
}
```

Comment: Hi, @MarioG8 thank you for the answer. It's funny because I did download and import 'react-ionicons' (I just missed putting that into the code snippet) but it's still strange like you said how it wasn't working. However 'react-icons/fa' works perfectly and just what I needed! Thank you again

Comment: @ReadingMan I am very happy for that !You're welcome ;-) The pleasure is all mine :-D  Glad I could help You.